# auto update my database when a entity changes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im using Spring for a web app and using `anotations` to define columns but when i change a `column type` that change is not reflected to my database.

Example:

```
  @Column(name = "detail")
  private String detail;
```

Changes to:

```
  @Column(name = "detail")
  private int detail;
```

My app.propierties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exampleapp
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =       org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following property. This will update your scheme when you run your application.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```